# OAuth Authorization Request Leakage Examples

Tags: oauth2

The OAuth attacker model (see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-15#section-3, A4) states that

> (A4) Attackers that can read, but not modify, the contents of the authorization request (i.e., the authorization request can leak, in the same manner as above, to an attacker).

This description is very clear and it's also mentioned in many articles and blogs, but usually actual scenarios where the authentication request leaks are not given. I can only come up with some rather constructed examples (e.g. referrer leakage, attacker can read access logs, etc.).

My questions are as follows:

1. What are some realistic scenarios in which the authorization request is leaked?
2. Have such vulnerabilities been found (or even exploited) in the wild?